# How to I implement notification service media control on Android YouTube player

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am a beginner I need help please I am using the [Android player librar](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player)y and I was able to load and play list but I am finding it difficult to implement a notification service that I can use to skip track, play and pause. Here is my code below it doesn't show the notification, I need assistance.

Android youtube library I am using com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:11.0.1

```
   tracker = new YouTubePlayerTracker();

            IFramePlayerOptions iFramePlayerOptions = new IFramePlayerOptions.Builder()
                    .controls(0)
                    .rel(0)
                    .ivLoadPolicy(0)
                    .ccLoadPolicy(0)
                    .build();

        youTubePlayerView.initialize(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
                YouTubePlayerUtils.loadOrCueVideo(
                        youTubePlayer,
                        getLifecycle(),
                        getPlayVideoId(),
                        0f

                );

                playPause.setChecked(true);
                youTubePlayerView.enableBackgroundPlayback(true);
                youTubePlayer.addListener(tracker);


 Bitmap artwork = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_play_trill_all);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_play_trill_all)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("message")
            .setLargeIcon(artwork)
            .addAction(R.drawable.music_player_like_off, "Dislike", null)
            .addAction(R.drawable.music_player_prev_btn, "Previous", null)
            .addAction(R.drawable.music_player_pause_btn, "Pause", null)
            .addAction(R.drawable.music_player_next_btn, "Next", null)
            .addAction(R.drawable.music_player_like_on, "Like", null)
            .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                    .setShowActionsInCompactView(1, 2, 3)
                    .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken()))
            .setSubText("Sub Text")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
            .build();

    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
        }

        }, true, iFramePlayerOptions);
```